Expo Go not Launching Correctly
I have an issue with expo go it start when I tried to do npx expo start that runs fine but i when I tried to link it to my expo go on my phone it bundles then after that nothing pops up except the default expo loading logo and I ran it before it worked but running it again nothing appears
i tried deleting the app deleting th expo go app still same issue

I often have this problem with expo Go, I usually do as you do: delete app cache and reinstall application. I've also had this problem when updating certain packages, try going back to a commit that was working fine and track the history of your packages in package.json to see those whose version has changed; that might solve the problem. More generally, check that the packages you're using are don't make expo loading indefinitely; start with a basic project and add them as you go along, making sure that the app doesn't crash.
